# Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Webkul\MpStripe\Observer\PreDispatchConfigSaveObserver does not exist

Tags: magento2, exception, stripe

How can I fix this?

I installed webkul MP Stripe Extension and I am getting this error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Webkul\MpStripe\Observer\PreDispatchConfigSaveObserver does not exist

Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Webkul\MpStripe\Observer\PreDispatchConfigSaveObserver does not exist
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Webkul\MpStripe\...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php:54]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('Webkul\MpStripe\...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:100]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Webkul\MpStripe\...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:70]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Webkul\MpStripe\...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/Event/ObserverFactory.php:33]
#5 Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverFactory->get('Webkul\MpStripe\...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php:72]
#6 Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(array('instance' => 'Webkul\MpStripe\...', 'name' => 'mpstripe_config_...'), &Magento\Framework\Event\Observer#0000000055c9482e0000000030981147#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php:66]
#7 Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('controller_actio...', array('controller_actio...' => &Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Save\Interceptor#0000000055c94da90000000030981147#, 'request' => &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000055c94e1d0000000030981147#)) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php:95]
#8 Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch('controller_actio...', array('controller_actio...' => &Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Save\Interceptor#0000000055c94da90000000030981147#, 'request' => &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000055c94e1d0000000030981147#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:101]
#9 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000055c94e1d0000000030981147#) called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php:231]
#10 Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000055c94e1d0000000030981147#) called at [vendor/magento/module-config/Controller/Adminhtml/System/AbstractConfig.php:69]
#11 Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\AbstractConfig->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000055c94e1d0000000030981147#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#12 Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Save\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000055c94e1d0000000030981147#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#13 Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000055c94e1d0000000030981147#) called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php:143]
#14 Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(&Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Save\Interceptor#0000000055c94da90000000030981147#, &Closure#0000000055c94dab0000000030981147#, &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000055c94e1d0000000030981147#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#15 Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000055c94e1d0000000030981147#) called at [app/code/Webkul/Marketplace/Plugin/App/Action/Context.php:54]
#16 Webkul\Marketplace\Plugin\App\Action\Context->aroundDispatch(&Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Save\Interceptor#0000000055c94da90000000030981147#, &Closure#0000000055c94dab0000000030981147#, &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000055c94e1d0000000030981147#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#17 Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Save\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000055c94e1d0000000030981147#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#18 Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Save\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000055c94e1d0000000030981147#), NULL) called at [generated/code/Magento/Config/Controller/Adminhtml/System/Config/Save/Interceptor.php:26]
#19 Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Save\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000055c94e1d0000000030981147#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:159]
#20 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000055c94e1d0000000030981147#, &Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Save\Interceptor#0000000055c94da90000000030981147#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:99]
#21 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000055c94e1d0000000030981147#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#22 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000055c94e1d0000000030981147#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#23 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000055c94e1d0000000030981147#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#24 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000055c94e1d0000000030981147#), array(array('default_store_se...', 'page_cache_from_...', 'storeCookieValid...', 'install', 'configHash'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#25 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000055c94e1d0000000030981147#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#26 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#27 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#0000000055c94ee00000000030981147#) called at [index.php:39]
</pre>
```

Comment: In this case please check if the observer is actually there or not

Answer (score 1):

Run this commands

`php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:di:compile`  
`php bin/magento cache:clean`

Comment: php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:di:compile